# Use Proxy in android without root

Tags: android, proxy

Im a android user and I want to use a Proxy in Android to connected to another server.
i used droid proxy but its need root android,I need some thing without root.
is there any application to work with proxy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its better to use [psiphone](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQFjAB&url=http://psiphon3.software.informer.com/1.0/&ei=1GhYUsWAFa614AO6sIHYBw&usg=AFQjCNGf47sRu3vVe4XtrJgsOkc1QW7gKA&sig2=CNNDq8dxOJ-VEe3i7Z_nag&bvm=bv.53899372,d.dmg) to connect to some free servers .

Answer (score 3):

You can try Drony

http://code.google.com/p/sandrop/wiki/HowToUseDronyWithOtherProxy

No need for root, but it works only on 3.x or higher os.

It is plain proxy, no other external servers, routes involved.

btw: send by Drony support

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a VPN? Its similar to a proxy, but it will get all your connections.